# What the difference between the family of Discrete Wavelet Transform？

Tags: wavelet

When I useed *Mathematica*,If found many Transforms in the list of Discrete Wavelet Transforms.

For example:

1. discrete wavelet transform (DWT)
2. stationary wavelet transform (SWT)
3. lifting wavelet transform (LWT)
4. discrete wavelet packet transform (DWPT)
5. stationary wavelet packet transform (SWPT)

I always use DWT,and found it can be used in many cases such as de-noising,filtering data,embedding watermarking,detecting the discontinuity and so on.

Is it different cases use different transforms?So how to know it?